# Pointer operation yields unexpected result

Tags: c, pointers, subtraction

I was expecting the code below to print 4 (since a float is 4 bytes), but it prints 1. Would someone explain why this happens?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float a[4]={0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3};
    printf("%d", &a[1]-&a[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always compile with *Compiler Warnings Enabled* and you would be shown `"warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=] printf("%d", &a[1]-&a[0]);"`

Comment: Pointer *arithmetic* is controlled by pointer `type`. Your type is `float` which is 4-bytes. How many 4-byte values are there between `&a[1]-&a[0]`? What does `printf("%ld\n", (&a[1]-&a[0]) * sizeof(float));` yield?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, change

```
  printf("%d", &a[1]-&a[0]);
```

to

```
 printf("%td", &a[1]-&a[0]);
```

as the result type of two subtraction yields a type `ptrdiff_t` and `%td` is the conversion specifier for that type.

That said, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.6, subtraction operator (*emphasis mine*)

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
>   or one past the last element of the array object; **the result is the difference of the
>   subscripts of the two array elements.** [....] In
>   other words, if the expressions `P` and `Q` point to, respectively, the `i`-th and `j`-th elements of
>   an array object, the expression `(P)-(Q)` has the value `i−j` provided the value fits in an object of type `ptrdiff_t`. [....]

In your case, `P` is `&a[1]` and `Q` is `&a[0]`, so `i` is `1` and `j` is `0`. Hence the result of the subtraction operation is `i-j`, i.e., `1-0`, `1`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the two pointers are 4 bytes apart. And if you were subtracting two integers you'd get 4. But `&a[1]` and `&a[0]` are of type `float *`. [Pointer arithmetic in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#C_arrays) takes into account the size of the thing being pointed to, so `&a[1]-&a[0]` is 1.

This is the basic means by which array indexing works. You can take advantage of this to iterate through an array without needing a separate index and instead terminating on a boundary such as [NaN](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nan).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float a[] = { 0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,NAN };

    float *iter = a;
    while(!isnan(*iter)) {
        printf("%f\n", *iter);
        iter++;
    }
}
```

If you instead cast the values to `unsigned int` you will indeed get 4.

```
printf("%u\n", (unsigned int)&a[1]-(unsigned int)&a[0]);
```

Comment: Why unsigned int? why not uintptr_t?